# Generating getServingUrl() in google cloud storage with NodeJs sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am using google cloud storage for storing images and also I have server running on NodeJs.

I want to generate for every image the `servingUrl`(aka magicUrl) which would on the fly generate images of different sizes(see more https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556#.1jtzu5kuo)

I tried using `gcloud` sdk to generate that, but I couldn't find anywhere `getServingUrl`.

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confusing Google App Engine and Google Cloud Storage. The [get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#Image_get_serving_url) method is only available in the Google App Engine SDK for Python, and is currently not available in the [Google Cloud Client Library for Node.js](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/).

Comment: Not ever Rest API endpoints are available for this. I am running a NodeJS application, how to approach this problem?